# Facebook Fan Home Page Redirect

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I speak any facebook fan page.
My aim is: I want to redirect "home (welcome) page of my fan", when i select facebook like button. Also, anytime i go to this fan page, again redirect home page. So, doesn't redirect fan wall page. So, home is main page. is it possible? (I know it is silly, but I want to learn it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is impossible. Facebook API lets you create applications which you have to launch. Adding events for I like button pressed is something that Facebook API don't let you modify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly...but if you are looking to subscribe to the "like" event, you can in fact do that:

```
FB.Event.subscribe(‘edge.create’, function(response) {
// do whatever you want after the like event
});
```